# Symfony2 Templating renderResponse causing CPU usage to shoot up

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a job that loops through the users and sends a personalized email based on their preferences. I am using the Templating engine in Symfony2 to generate the HTML.

Basically something like this runs in a loop:

```
public function getHTML($user) 
{
    $templating = $this->getContainer()->get('templating');
    $html = $templating->renderResponse( 
                'recommendation.html.twig',
                 array(
                   'user' => $user
                 )
             )->getContent();
    return $html;
}
```

The problem is CPU usage shoots up to 100% and it takes longer and longer to process each user. Here is some data:

```
Took 5.4851469993591 seconds 
Took 12.790720939636 seconds 
Took 23.007503032684 seconds 
Took 34.852293014526 seconds 
Took 43.901736021042 seconds 
Took 66.028288125992 seconds
```

Each line represents the time taken to process 100 users. So the first 100 users took 5 seconds, next 12 seconds, and so on.

Any suggestions on what I can do to improve performance?

Comment: Take profiler and profile what takes that much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll likely be doctrine accumulating a massive identity map of managed entities as you fetch them.

In each iteration of your email send, look at doing an entity manager [clear or detach](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities)

Best to use this in combination with an iterated result, there's a [good example in the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#id1).

It can make a huge difference to speed and memory consumption for jobs that do a large amount of iterations.

Doctrine isn't generally great for long running scripts without a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks! I did some profiling as @zerkms suggested and found out that it was indeed doctrine the culprit.